# Android ndk build ignoring APP_OPTIM and LOCAL_ARM_MODE

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I have a project (in Android Studio 2.2.2) using the ffmpeg native library.

I have been able to build my project with no problems until recently.

Now I am getting the message:

```
Error: instruction not supported in Thumb16 mode -- `adds r2,r5,r4,lsr#31'
Error: selected processor does not support Thumb mode `itet ne'
```

I have set APP_OPTIM to debug in my Application.mk file and LOCAL_ARM_MODE to arm in my Android.mk file.

However, when I try to build my project, it is still showing these two error messages.

Please tell me if you need more information to help me solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug. Can you provide a test case? https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues. I can only think of a couple ways this could have gone wrong on your end. 1. You set `LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm` outside the module definition, or perhaps not in all module definitions. 2. `-mthumb` is being manually set somewhere in your cflags.

Comment: 1. The Android.mk file where I have set `LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm`, is located in the directory: app/src/main/jni/ do I need to add this to the Android.mk files in all subdirectories?  2. Could you point me into the direction of where I would I look to see `-mthumb` is being set manually? (Just a disclaimer, I've only been in android development for a year and I have inherited this project from the previous dev)

Comment: It needs to be in every *module*. Anything that begins with `LOCAL_` needs to be specified per module.